# Link Command Question

Tags: linux, command

I am looking for a simple command in GNU/Linux to count all files in a directory beginning with `pa`.

I have already executed the command to show all the files beginning with `pa` which I used `find /etc/file/magic -name "pa*"` and it shows up 4.

However, I need a command to actually count this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a pipe to the word count command with the line option:

```
$ find /etc/file/magic -name "pa*" |wc -l
```

Comment: This works in most cases, but doesn’t deal well with filenames containing newlines ;-). See the linked duplicate for a nice workaround using `find`.

Comment: That's Fantastic, worked great for me thank you

Comment: @Deirdre You are welcome! By the way, you can also upvote answers ;-)